# Extract txt file subset using command line

Tags: bash, parsing, shell, text, command-line

i'm a command line NB and i'm trying to lern basics to pars txt files. Is not an easy task because i connot find exaustive guides or manual to give me the basic.

Given so, i have a VERY LARGE txt space separated file (ca. 3 milion line) like:

```
-179.250000 89.916664 -9999
-179.083328 89.916664 -456
-178.916672 89.916664 -7543
```

i'd like to get only the line where the first column value is comprised between 33 and 40 and second column value between -13 and 28.

Many thanks for any help,

Don

Comment: what have you tried? can you provide sample input.txt and expected results?

Answer (score 2):

awk:

```
$1 <= 40 && $1 >= 33 && $2 <= 28 && $2 >= -13 {
  print
}
```

...

```
$ awk -f script.awk <<< '-179.250000 89.916664 -9999
> -179.083328 89.916664 -456
> -178.916672 89.916664 -7543
> 34 0 123
> 34 -54 123
> 20 20 20
> '
34 0 123
```

Comment: +1. awk is the perfect tool those "field N between this and that value" jobs.